# Locking From Temp Table - SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, locking

I have just implemented a new database on our live environment, this database is fed information by a service brokers from our two transactional databases.  When the messages come into the new database we have a series of stored procedures which manipulate the feed for each specific user.

I also have another set of stored procedures which re-manipulate the data by user instead of by vehicle, these are used by our maintenance screens to ensure we can change users visibility of the data.

The below stored procedure keeps locking up  I have now amended this sp to update a temp table first and then just undertake one update against the main database, however this has not aided the situation, I have also amended so I can update in smaller batches and if this fails keep retrying until it is successful.  This works 100% on our dev environment but on live it keeps locking.   The throughput on the servicebrokers is not great enough to register the number of failures, I therefore believe I am locking myself within this sp?

I have included ---'THIS UPDATE KEEPS LOCKING'  at the point of failure.

What could be causing this locking behavior?

```
USE [Isight]
```

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[UserVisibilityForVehicles]    Script Date: 07/18/2014 14:43:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserVisibilityForVehicles]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Username VARCHAR(50) 
 WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
PRINT 'UserVisibilityForVehicles Started'

-- Now Start to check security for user.

IF EXISTS ( SELECT ID FROM dbo.SecurityTable WHERE userid = @Username AND Deleted = 0)
BEGIN


        CREATE TABLE #VehicleToUsers(ID BIGINT, NewRecord BIT DEFAULT(0))
        CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_VehicleToUsers ON #VehicleToUsers(ID)
        CREATE NonCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_NewRecord ON #VehicleToUsers(ID)

        INSERT INTO #VehicleToUsers
                ( ID )
        (
            SELECT Distinct Veh.[ID]
            FROM [iSight].[dbo].[Vehicle] Veh WITH (NOLOCK) 
            INNER JOIN SecurityTable WITH (NOLOCK) ON  Veh.[System] = SecurityTable.[System]
            WHERE SecurityType = 1  AND UserID = @Username AND SecurityTable.deleted = 0 
        )

        INSERT INTO #VehicleToUsers
                ( ID )
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT Veh.[ID]
            FROM [iSight].[dbo].[Vehicle] Veh WITH (NOLOCK) 
            INNER JOIN SecurityTable WITH (NOLOCK) ON Veh.[System] = SecurityTable.[System] AND Veh.CurrentSite = SecurityTable.[Site]
            WHERE SecurityType = 2 AND UserID = @Username AND SecurityTable.deleted = 0 
        )



                    BEGIN
                        PRINT 'UserVisibilityForVehicles: ' + @Username
                        INSERT INTO #VehicleToUsers
                                    ( ID )
                            (
                        SELECT  DISTINCT   Vehicle.ID
                        FROM         Manufacturer WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                                              ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer WITH (NOLOCK) ON Manufacturer.ID = ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.ManufacturerID INNER JOIN
                                              ManufacturerMake WITH (NOLOCK) ON Manufacturer.ID = ManufacturerMake.ManufacturerID INNER JOIN
                                              Vehicle WITH (NOLOCK) ON ManufacturerMake.Make = Vehicle.Make AND ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.Agreement = Vehicle.CurrentAgreement INNER JOIN
                                              SecurityTable WITH (NOLOCK) ON Manufacturer.ManufacturerGroupID = SecurityTable.ManufacturerGroupID AND Vehicle.System = SecurityTable.System
                        WHERE     (SecurityTable.SecurityType = 3)  AND (SecurityTable.UserID = @Username) AND ManufacturerMake.Deleted = 0 AND ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.Deleted = 0 AND SecurityTable.deleted = 0 
                            )

                            INSERT INTO #VehicleToUsers
                                    ( ID )
                            (
                        SELECT DISTINCT Vehicle.ID
                        FROM         Manufacturer WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                                              ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer WITH (NOLOCK) ON Manufacturer.ID = ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.ManufacturerID INNER JOIN
                                              ManufacturerMake WITH (NOLOCK) ON Manufacturer.ID = ManufacturerMake.ManufacturerID INNER JOIN
                                              Vehicle WITH (NOLOCK) ON ManufacturerMake.Make = Vehicle.Make AND ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.Agreement = Vehicle.CurrentAgreement INNER JOIN
                                              SecurityTable WITH (NOLOCK) ON Vehicle.System = SecurityTable.System AND Manufacturer.ID = SecurityTable.ManufacturerID
                        WHERE     (SecurityTable.SecurityType = 4) AND (SecurityTable.UserID = @Username) AND ManufacturerMake.Deleted = 0 AND ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.Deleted = 0 AND SecurityTable.deleted = 0 
                            )

                                INSERT INTO #VehicleToUsers
                                    ( ID )
                            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT Vehicle.ID
                                FROM         Manufacturer WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                                                      ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer WITH (NOLOCK) ON Manufacturer.ID = ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.ManufacturerID INNER JOIN
                                                      ManufacturerMake WITH (NOLOCK) ON Manufacturer.ID = ManufacturerMake.ManufacturerID INNER JOIN
                                                      Vehicle WITH (NOLOCK) ON ManufacturerMake.Make = Vehicle.Make AND ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.Agreement = Vehicle.CurrentAgreement INNER JOIN
                                                      SecurityTable WITH (NOLOCK) ON Vehicle.System = SecurityTable.System AND Manufacturer.ID = SecurityTable.ManufacturerID AND 
                                                      ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.ID = SecurityTable.ManufacturerAgreementSub INNER JOIN
                                                      ManufacturerUserAgreementSubcustomer WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
                                                      ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.ID = ManufacturerUserAgreementSubcustomer.ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomerID AND 
                                                      SecurityTable.ManufacturerID = ManufacturerUserAgreementSubcustomer.ManufacturerID AND 
                                                      SecurityTable.UserID = ManufacturerUserAgreementSubcustomer.UserName
                                WHERE     (SecurityTable.SecurityType = 5) AND (SecurityTable.UserID = @Username) AND (ManufacturerMake.Deleted = 0) AND 
                                                      (ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.Deleted = 0) AND (ManufacturerUserAgreementSubcustomer.Deleted = 0) AND SecurityTable.deleted = 0 


                            )


                                    INSERT INTO #VehicleToUsers
                                    ( ID )
                            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT Vehicle.ID
                                FROM         Manufacturer WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                                                      ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer WITH (NOLOCK) ON Manufacturer.ID = ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.ManufacturerID INNER JOIN
                                                      ManufacturerMake WITH (NOLOCK) ON Manufacturer.ID = ManufacturerMake.ManufacturerID INNER JOIN
                                                      Vehicle WITH (NOLOCK) ON ManufacturerMake.Make = Vehicle.Make AND ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.Agreement = Vehicle.CurrentAgreement AND 
                                                      ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.Subcustomer = Vehicle.CurrentSubCustomer INNER JOIN
                                                      SecurityTable WITH (NOLOCK) ON Vehicle.System = SecurityTable.System AND Manufacturer.ID = SecurityTable.ManufacturerID AND 
                                                      ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.ID = SecurityTable.ManufacturerAgreementSub INNER JOIN
                                                      ManufacturerUserAgreementSubcustomer WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
                                                      ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.ID = ManufacturerUserAgreementSubcustomer.ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomerID AND 
                                                      SecurityTable.UserID = ManufacturerUserAgreementSubcustomer.UserName AND 
                                                      SecurityTable.ManufacturerID = ManufacturerUserAgreementSubcustomer.ManufacturerID
                                WHERE     (SecurityTable.SecurityType = 6) AND (SecurityTable.UserID = @Username) AND (ManufacturerMake.Deleted = 0) AND 
                                                      (ManufacturerAgreementSubcustomer.Deleted = 0) AND (ManufacturerUserAgreementSubcustomer.Deleted = 0) AND SecurityTable.deleted = 0 
                            )


                    END

        CREATE TABLE #VehicleToUserCopy(ID BIGINT, vehicleTableID BIGINT, Deleted BIT DEFAULT(1), UpdatedAt DATETIME DEFAULT (GETDATE()), UpdatedBy VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT('UserVisibilityForVehicles-Update'), NextToUpdate BIT DEFAULT(0))

        CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_ID ON #VehicleToUserCopy(ID)
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_VehicleTableID ON #VehicleToUserCopy(vehicleTableID)
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_NextToUpdate ON #VehicleToUserCopy(NextToUpdate)
        INSERT INTO #VehicleToUserCopy
                ( ID ,
                  vehicleTableID ,
                  Deleted
                )
        (
        SELECT ID, vehicleTableID, Deleted
        FROM dbo.VehicleToUser WITH (nolock)
        WHERE Username = @Username

        )


        PRINT 'Starting to do updates'
        --Not required as default set to 1
        ----UPDATE VehicleToUser
        ----SET DELETED = 1
        ----,UpdatedAt = GETDATE()
        ----,UpdatedBy = 'UserVisibilityForVehicles'
        ----FROM dbo.VehicleToUser WITH (NOLOCK)
        ----LEFT JOIN #VehicleToUsers AS UsersVehicles ON VehicleToUser.VehicleTableID = UsersVehicles.ID
        ----WHERE UserName = @Username AND UsersVehicles.ID IS null

        PRINT 'Starting to do updates - Set Deleted = 0'




        SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 1000 -- set to  second
        DECLARE @Tries tinyint


        UPDATE #VehicleToUserCopy
        SET Deleted = 0
        FROM #VehicleToUserCopy AS VehicleToUserCopy
        inner JOIN #VehicleToUsers AS UsersVehicles ON VehicleToUserCopy.VehicleTableID = UsersVehicles.ID




        INSERT INTO VehicleToUser(UserName, VehicleTableID, DELETED, UpdatedAt, UpdatedBy)
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT @Username, TempVehicle.ID, 0 , GETDATE(), 'UserVisibilityForVehicles-Insert'
            FROM #VehicleToUsers AS TempVehicle
            LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT VehicleTableID
                        FROM #VehicleToUserCopy WITH (NOLOCK)
                      ) AS [VehicleToUser] ON TempVehicle.ID = [VehicleToUser].VehicleTableID
            WHERE [VehicleToUser].VehicleTableID IS null

        )

        DECLARE @ID bigint

        SELECT @ID = ID FROM #VehicleToUserCopy
        WHILE @@rowcount > 0 
            BEGIN

                    SET ROWCOUNT 1000
                    SELECT @Tries = 1
                    WHILE @Tries <= 3

                          BEGIN

                         BEGIN TRANSACTION

                         BEGIN TRY

                                UPDATE #VehicleToUserCopy SET NextToUpdate = 1


                                 ---'THIS UPDATE KEEPS LOCKING'
                                UPDATE dbo.VehicleToUser
                                SET Deleted = VehicleToUserCopy.Deleted
                                , UpdatedAt = GETDATE()
                                , UpdatedBy = VehicleToUserCopy.UpdatedBy
                                FROM VehicleToUser
                                inner JOIN #VehicleToUserCopy  AS VehicleToUserCopy ON VehicleToUser.ID = VehicleToUserCopy.ID
                                WHERE VehicleToUserCopy.NextToUpdate = 1            

                                PRINT 'WORKED'
                                DELETE FROM #VehicleToUserCopy WHERE NextToUpdate = 1   
                                COMMIT    

                          -- therefore we can leave our loop
                          BREAK

                         END TRY

                         BEGIN CATCH

                                ROLLBACK --always rollback 


                            PRINT 'Rolled Back '
                          -- Now check for Blocking errors 1222 or Deadlocks 1205 and if its a deadlock wait for a while to see if that helps
                             SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
                              IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205 OR ERROR_NUMBER() = 1222

                                BEGIN

                                     -- if its a deadlock wait 2 seconds then try again
                                   IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205
                                     BEGIN  -- wait 2 seconds to see if that helps the deadlock

                                            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'
                                     END   

                                   -- no need to wait for anything for BLOCKING ERRORS as our LOCK_TIMEOUT is going to wait for half a second anyway
                                   -- and if it hasn't finished by then (500ms x 3 attempts = 1.5 seconds) there is no point waiting any longer

                                END      


                                 SELECT @Tries = @Tries + 1  -- increment and try again for 3 goes

                          -- we carry on until we reach our limit i.e 3 attempts
                          CONTINUE    

                           END CATCH

                          END



                SELECT @ID = ID FROM #VehicleToUserCopy 
            End


        SET ROWCOUNT 0


        DROP TABLE #VehicleToUsers


END
ELSE

BEGIN
        DELETE FROM dbo.VehicleToUser WHERE username = @Username
        DELETE FROM dbo.VehicleToUser_UserCurrentImageCount WHERE username = @Username
        DELETE FROM dbo.VehicleToUser_UsersCurrentVehicles WHERE username = @Username

End
```

Comment: I would recommend you stop littering you database with NOLOCK hints. Are you ok with duplicate and/or missing data?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your update slightly. I have seen some inconsistent results when using an update like this and you update the base table. You should instead update the alias.

```
UPDATE v
SET Deleted = VCopy.Deleted
, UpdatedAt = GETDATE()
, UpdatedBy = VCopy.UpdatedBy
FROM VehicleToUser v
inner JOIN #VehicleToUserCopy  AS VCopy ON v.ID = VCopy.ID
WHERE VCopy.NextToUpdate = 1
```